# Proof that a binary [n, k] code, C, has 2^(n-k) cosets...

Tags: coding-theory

I know this is an amateur question, but I am confused as to why this is true.

I've thought about it like this: |C| = 2^k, and |[GF(2)]^n| = 2^n, so there are 2^n - 2^k distinct vectors in GF(2)^n and not in C, and each one generates a single coset.

Thus, there should be 2^n - 2^k + 1 cosets (since C itself is a coset), but I am obviously wrong so I'm not sure how to prove this properly.  Any help is massively appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct up to this: $|C| = 2^k$, and $|GF(2^n)|=F_2^n = 2^n$, so there are $2^n - 2^k$ distinct vectors in $GF(2^n)$ and not in $C$.

But each one not generates a single coset. In every coset, there are $2^k$ elements, so there are $\frac{2^n}{2^k}= 2^{n-k}$ cosets in $F_2^n$.

Comment: Ok so since there are 2^k elements in each coset and each of those elements defines the same coset, we can partition the 2^n elements in GF(2)^n into groups of size 2^k where each member of the partition consists of the members of a unique coset...and 2^n elements divided into groups of size 2^k yields 2^(n-k) groups.  I should have seen it this way from the start.  Apologies for the dumb question.  Thanks though!

Comment: @RichardGroenewald Please accept the answers to your questions, if you find them satisfying. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers